# md5 in linux and python

Tags: python, linux, md5

I am using md5 algo for hashing same string in python and linux but I get different values can some one point out whats wrong

in linux:
`echo "logdir" | md5sum - | awk '{print $1}'`

```
gives: aba76197efa97e6bd4e542846471b391
```

in python:
`md5.new("logdir".encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()`

```
gives: ee6da4c228cfaebfda7f14e4371a097d
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`echo` will add a newline unless you explicitly tell it not to via `echo -n`.

```
$ echo -n "logdir" | md5sum - | awk '{print $1}'
ee6da4c228cfaebfda7f14e4371a097d
```

From [man echo](http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo):

```
DESCRIPTION
       Echo the STRING(s) to standard output.

       -n     do not output the trailing newline
```